# Internal Server Error? Why is this happening?

Tags: database

All normal to start my website, but to click on any of the links, menus, etc, I get redirected to this with the following message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request ...

Why is this happening?

What happens is that had risen another database project (one domain to another) I think it has a lot to do this.

There a way to fix it? Perhaps when exporting the database did wrong, what I want is that this database will serve me for several other projects. other domains.
I need your comments, help or suggestion

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` file in Drupal root ?

Comment: Did that solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q. Why is this happening?**

This can happen if the .htaccess files in your Drupal directory use settings or trigger actions which are not supported by your Apache server config. If you're not running the server yourself, but are registered with a webhost, you can either ask your webhost to enable the options in question, or just comment them out in the htaccess files.

1. The options which are known to cause an Error 500 are:

   Options -Indexes
2. It may also occur when setting very permissive file permissions (777) and your hoster added some security checks to avoid this. Try to lower permissions.
3. Another problem can occur if you're using .htaccess files using UTF-8 codification with Byte-Order Mark (BOM). Reencode your .htaccess files properly without BOM to solve this.
4. This error can also manifests itself as a PHP error. Try adding the code below to one of your PHP files such as local.php, then checking the error log file it generates.

   ini_set('log_errors', 1);
   ini_set('error_log', 'errorlog.txt');

Read:

[HTTP Error 500 Internal server error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)

[List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Excellent reply

Simply, I removed that file. "Htaccess" and issue solved :D

Thanks  a lot @Nikhil